Continuous deployment from GitHub Action to Google Cloud VM using Docker
For university, I am creating quite a simple project using Node.js. What I want is to set up a continuous delivery to a virtual machine hosted in the Google Cloud.
Using the GitHub Actions, I created a yaml to build the project with node.js.
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x, 20.x, 22.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present

Then, I created the Dockerfile for the creation of the container
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "app.js"]

Now, I can't find an action to deploy this image to the virtual machine in Google. I read those documents:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-nodejs-service
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/how-to-deploy-github-cloud-run-using-cloud-build?authuser=3#0
https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-push-docker-image

but they are very complicated and there is no integration with Docker. Is there any documentation or can you give me the yaml to use for it?

You can access your virtual machine using SSH.
In your github actions use any SSH action to connect your virtual machine, and pull the latest code there. So that whenever code on main branch is updated, automatically the code is delivered to your virtual machine.

Generate SSH keys on your local machine using this command.
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

Copy generated public key to "~/.ssh/authorized_keys" file on your VM.

Add the private key,VM IP,docker username and docker hub token to your GitHub repository as a secret.

Add a new step in your YAML file after your build step to login into docker hub and updating the image.

After that add new job that pulls your latest image into VM via SSH access from docker hub.


name: CI/CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: '16'

    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present

    - name: Login to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@v3
      with:
        username: ${{ vars.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

    - name: Build and Push Docker Image
      run: |
        docker build -t your-dockerhub-username/your-app-name:latest .
        docker push your-dockerhub-username/your-app-name:latest

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Install SSH client
      run: sudo apt-get install -y openssh-client

    - name: Add SSH key
      uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
      with:
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        known_hosts: ${{ secrets.GCP_VM_IP }}

    - name: Deploy to Google Cloud VM
      run: |
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@${{ secrets.GCP_VM_IP }} << 'EOF'
        docker pull your-dockerhub-username/your-app-name:latest
        docker stop your-container-name || true
        docker rm your-container-name || true
        docker run -d --name your-container-name -p 3000:3000 your-dockerhub-username/your-app-name:latest
        EOF


This will connect to your VM and pull-down latest code from your repo. Now every time code is pushed on main branch, Github Actions will automatically deploy latest version of your code to VM.

Your answer to this question was deleted and in a comment you asked why. I do not know whether anyone else responded, but here is my understanding. The original question asked for "good documentation or resources, ... or ... a good sample". This is explicitly off topic as per bullet 3 of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. The learning point is to concentrate on giving answers to good questions and avoid wasting your valuable time on off-topic questions.

Bullet 3 states:  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
